# ¿Podemos tener anuncios de promoción de la comunidad?

Tags: característica-nueva, estado-completado, anuncios-de-comunidad

Veo que muchos sitios de Stack Exchange tienen campañas de promoción de la comunidad. Las llaman *Community Promotion Ads* y consisten en la posibilidad de que la comunidad elija qué anuncios quiere que aparezcan en la columna de la derecha. Estos anuncios llevan a páginas de la red Stack Exchange o a proyectos de código abierto.

Mejor copio cómo lo explicó Robert Cartaino (director de desarrollo de las comunidades de Stack Exchange) en la entrada del blog [Community Promotion Ads](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/):

> Puede que hayáis visto nuestros [anuncios basados en votos para proyectos de código abierto](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/)<sup>1</sup> en Stack Overflow - los usuarios de Stack Overflow crean anuncios para su proyecto favorito de código abierto y la comunidad vota por los proyectos que les gustaría ver promocionados en el sitio.
>
> Dada la popularidad de este programa, hemos extendido este programa a todos los sitios públicos de Stack Exchange.

Sigue luego:

> La idea es ayudar a los visitantes a darse cuenta de las cosas interesantes que vuestra comunidad está haciendo y ayudar a promocionar las actividades que consideran importantes. Y todo es visible allí mismo, en la barra derecha al lado de cada pregunta, en la página de inicio.

Suena bien, ¿no? Seguro que muchos de nosotros podemos listar proyectos interesantes que podrían ser aún mejores si se les da promoción para conseguir nuevos voluntarios.

Ved dos ejemplos:

- [English language learners](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2854/3462)
- [Unix & Linux](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3854/40596)

En ambos casos funcionó muy bien y se obtuvieron una serie de anuncios de otros sitios o proyectos, redundando en la idea de Stack Exchange de crear comunidades de conocimiento.

Entonces, ¿podríamos tener tales anuncios de promoción aquí en Stack Overflow en español?

Nótese que en [*¿Cuál es el proceso de los empleados de Stack Exchange cuando se lanza un sitio?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199551/209901) se comentó:

> **Sitio graduado**
>
> En este punto el sitio se sustenta por sí solo prácticamente. La comunidad pasa a tener a su disposición nuevas funcionalidades como crear un blog o sus "Anuncios de promoción de la comunidad" enviando sugerencias a la publicación en Meta con este nombre.

Por tanto entiendo que deberemos esperar a que se gradúe el sitio. Sin embargo, tal y como comenta Mariano en los comentarios, la funcionalidad de tener blog sí está presente pese a no estar graduados.

Por tanto, ¿es posible tener anuncios ahora pese a no estar graduados?

---

<sup>1 [Free Vote-Based Advertising for Open Source Projects](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/), por Jeff Atwood, uno de los dos fundadores de Stack Overflow. Allí explica la idea original de incluir estos anuncios para proyectos de *open source*.</sup>

Comment: Me parece una idea muy interesante la verdad. +1

Comment: ¿Esto es posible para las comunidades que están en beta público?

Comment: @dwarandae buena pregunta. Lo miré... y no, debemos esperar a que se gradúe. He añadido una respuesta con esta información.

Comment: SOes tampoco sigue lo que llamaríamos un _proceso típico_ de beta. Creo que no estaría mal consultar si es necesario esperar a la graduación. A la par de anuncios de promoción de la comunidad menciona "crear un blog", algo que JuanM ya comenzó.

Comment: @Mariano bien visto. Añado por tanto esta referencia a la pregunta a la espera de respuesta oficial.

Comment: Véase aquí: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1185/anuncios-de-promoci%C3%B3n-de-la-comunidad-2016 La respuesta es un fuerte ¡si!

Comment: ¡Excelente noticia! Cada uno de estos pasos son un claro indicio de la evolución del sitio... @JuanM creo que debería ir como respuesta ;-)

Comment: @JuanM ¡qué bien! Sí, como dice Mariano iría bien ponerlo como respuesta para que se vea mejor el nexo de unión con la gran noticia de que ¡ya tenemos los anuncios de promoción de la comunidad disponibles!

Comment: Preferí dejar el anuncio tal y como está simplemente porque vamos a tener que enlazar a esa pregunta regularmente mientras cambiamos los ciclos de los anuncios.

Comment: @JuanM ajá, entiendo. Yo me refería (y supongo que Mariano también) a publicar tu comentario como respuesta y enlazar a tu publicación canónica. Bueno, detalles sin importancia al fin y al cabo, acabo de pubicarlo yo y así queda más visible. ¡Gracias Juan!

Comment: ☝☝☝☝☝ exacto. La costumbre de querer cerrar todas las publicaciones que se pueda

Comment: @Mariano por nuestro afán de tenerlo todo ordenado, en esta edición de Winter Bash deberían darnos un sombrero con forma de escoba :P

Comment: Ya entiendo...jeje.  El problema fue que cuando publique mi respuesta como una respuesta, el sistema lo convirtió a un comentario siendo que había poco texto.  Estaba a punto de salir y no edite la respuesta para hacerla más larga así que se quedo como comentario....

Comment: Jajaja. Totalmente. Busquemos una pala y una escoba y hacemos equipo :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tal y como indicó [Juan M en los comentarios](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1140/podemos-tener-anuncios-de-promoci%C3%B3n-de-la-comunidad?noredirect=1#comment3020_1140):

> Véase aquí: [Anuncios de promoción de la comunidad - 2017](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1185/83) La respuesta es un fuerte ¡si!

Esta es una muy buena noticia que nos llega antes incluso de estar graduados.