# Anuncios de promoción de la comunidad - 2017

Tags: discusión, anuncios-de-comunidad, llamada-a-la-accion

Se ha [preguntado sobre los anuncios de proyectos de Open Source aquí en Stack OVerflow en español](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1140/podemos-tener-anuncios-de-promoci%C3%B3n-de-la-comunidad). Me gustaría anunciar que tienen la oportunidad desde ahora para [crear una publicidad o anuncio a un proyecto Open Source que les interese](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/).

[image]

Se necesita que proporcionen una imagen gráfica para el proyecto de programación Open Source en forma de una respuesta a esta pregunta (con el formato correcto), y me encargaré de agregar esos anuncios  a la rotación para este sitio. No hay cargo para esta oferta - es completamente gratis.

### Requerimientos de los anuncios

Debe de ser una publicidad que **solicite la participación y las contribuciones de programadores que escriban el código fuente del proyecto**. Estos anuncios no se usarán como anuncios para productos de consumo general que resultan ser Open Source.  Esto es para encontrar a programadores que ayuden a contribuir el código necesario o otra cosa parecida (documentación, revisión de código, corrección de errores, etc).

El anuncio debe ser una creación original que no haya aparecido anteriormente en ningún sitio de Stack Overflow (internacional, en inglés o propio).

Para que esto funcione, la respuesta a esta pregunta **debe** conformarse a las siguientes reglas:

### Plantilla de respuesta

```
[![texto alternativo si la imagen no se muestra][1]][2]
    [1]: http://url-de-la-imagen
    [2]: http://url-del-clickthrough (a donde se quiera mandar a la gente)
```

Favor de **no agregar nada más al cuerpo del post**. Si necesitas escribir algo extra, ponlo en los comentarios.

### Requisitos de la imagen

- La imagen que compartas debe de ser de **300 pixels por 250 pixels**, o lo doble si el DPI es alto.
- La imagen se debe encontrar en nuestro uploader estándar (imgur).
- El formato debe ser GIF o PNG.
- No a los GIFs animados.
- El limite absoluto del file debe ser **150 KB**
- Debe incluirse un bordo de 1px si el fondo (o una parte del fondo) es blanco, 2px si es de alto DPI.

El rendimiento, que últimamente se servirá en una ranura de publicaciones en Stack Overflow, se puede ver preliminarmente al hacer clic en este URL:

http://rads.stackoverflow.com/ossads/300x250

### Umbral de puntuaje

Existe un **umbral de puntuaje mínimo** que cada respuesta debe alcanzar (por ahora es 6) antes de ser incluida en la rotación de Stack Overflow en español. Puedes ver todos los anuncios que llevan esa puntuación y cumplen los requisitos aquí:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/327559

**Nótese:** *Si la imagen que se proporcione ya ha sido compartida en otras ocasiones, no será elegible para este ciclo.  Sin embargo, si se diseña algo nuevo para el mismo proyecto antes anunciado, tendrá oportunidad de entrar a la rotación siempre y cuando reciba los votos necesarios.*.

Comment: [meta-tag:característica-nueva] es para solicitar características nuevas, aquí se está anunciando una, por ello, edité las etiquetas.

Comment: Jo, es una pena que pusieras toda la infraestructura y no se esté aprovechando. Ya que disponemos del espacio, ¿podrían aceptarse anuncios de [spanish.se]?

Comment: Juan M: ¿es o no posible plantear anuncios de [spanish.se]? ¿Sería posible en algún otro modo del tipo [Community Promotion Ads - 2017](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4293/6997)?

Answer (score 2):

¡Recompensas! No sé si será posible conseguir una traducción a esta página...

[image: Recompensas en SOes ahora mismo]

Comment: ¿Donde se encuentra esta página o imagen?

Comment: @JuanM por [lo que veo](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1874) está en un repositorio de GitHub: https://github.com/51cards/Stack-Exchange-Bounty-Ad La imagen es estática (menos los numeritos). A ver si conseguimos hallar a los programadores y hacemos una pull request con una imagen en castellano.