# ¿Se pueden promover comunidades técnicas desde Stack Overflow en español?

Tags: soporte, comunidad

¿Existe en Stack Overflow en español o en general en Stack Exchange algo que permita promover comunidades técnicas?

Pertenezco a una comunidad que me gustaría ayudar a potenciar y creo que Stack Overflow puede ser un buen nicho para encontrar personas que quieran unirse a la comunidad.

¿Se puede publicar en algún lado esto?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Respuesta corta

Sí se puede, ya sea mediante

- anuncios pagados
- anuncios de la comunidad
- de forma orgánica en preguntas y respuestas

## Explicación

En el pie de página de las páginas de este sitio se encuentra el enlace [información de publicidad](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertise), la información está en inglés, pero basta decir que tiene costo.

Otro "mecanismo" y que es gratuito son los "anuncios de la comunidad" pero estos deben ser de proyectos de código abierto. Más detalles en [Anuncios de promoción de la comunidad - 2017](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1185/65)

Un mecanismo más, es que si tu comunidad ya publica contenido de calidad y se puede considerar una fuente confiable, puedes incluir enlaces a dicho contenido siempre y cuando incluyas las partes esenciales al preguntas y respuestas, incluso si la comunidad fuera autora de librerías y frameworks podría crearse una etiqueta como ocurre con [jquery](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) por mencionar una.

## Artículos de ayuda relacionados

- [¿Puedo apoyar mi producto en este sitio?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/product-support)
- [No te conviertas en un spammer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)

Comment: Pues tienes razón, esta es la forma correcta de interpretar la pregunta, me había equivocado.