# ¿Queremos tener avisos comunitarios? ¿De qué tipo?

Tags: discusión, community-ads, anuncios-de-comunidad

Muchas gracias a [@gbianchi](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/324/gbianchi) por la traducción.

---

Muchos sitios de Stack Exchange son bastante populares (en otras palabras, tienen una gran cantidad de visitas). Utilizamos parte de las visitas para anuncios pagados. [Lo hacemos con cuidado, sin sobrecargar los sitios](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/03/25/responsible-advertising-feed-a-programmer/). Incluso con los anuncios pagados, todavía tenemos un exceso de anuncios en el inventario.

#### [¡Este año nos complace ofrecer a la comunidad el uso de espacios publicitarios gratuitos en Stack Overflow en español!](Https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/05/31/community-promotion-ads/)

Por favor, compartan lo que piensan:

1. ¿Les gustaría tener anuncios de la comunidad en el sitio o es mejor sin él?
2. Si desean anuncios comunitarios en el sitio, ¿qué tipo de anuncios deberían ser?

#### Tipos de anuncios de la comunidad

Se alienta a todas las comunidades de Stack Exchange a promover:

- Actividades sociales comunitarias en metas por sitio.
- Herramientas y aplicaciones gratuitas/de código abierto relacionadas con el sitio.
- Conferencias u otros eventos que pueden ser útiles para los usuarios.
- Cualquier otra cosa que realmente le interese a la comunidad.

Solo hay un sitio excepcional: Stack Overflow en inglés. Tiene una restricción adicional: [el anuncio debe solicitar la participación y contribución de los programadores que escriben el código fuente real](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/12/19/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/). Nuestro sitio está bastante cerca de Stack Overflow en inglés. Parece que deberíamos tener una restricción similar ... ¿O no deberíamos?

¿Qué pensáis? ¿Queréis tener anuncios de la comunidad? Si es así, ¿qué tipo de anuncios de la comunidad se deberían permitir en Stack Overflow en español? ¡Por favor compartid vuestros pensamientos!

Tened en cuenta que nos reservamos el derecho de ejercer control editorial y rechazar cualquier anuncio que no nos resulte cómodo publicar en el sitio.

Comment: Great one! Since you are using the special [meta-tag:community-ads], does it mean that they will be extracted directly from the answers like [in other sites](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3311/1674)?

Comment: uhhh we need that!!!!

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar'  ¡Correcto!

Comment: Is this why @gbianchi 's ad is now visible in Stack Overflow? https://i.imgur.com/zHVe3oc.png

Comment: @Nicolas cool! Shouldn't we have the specifications of the images, so that they render properly?

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Toda la información estará en la próxima publicación, si los usuarios dicen que quieren tener anuncios de la comunidad =)

Comment: @Nicolas ah right, I thought this was the post where such images would be published. Thanks! I am going to post an answer

Answer (score 4):

#### ¡Sí!

Creo que es interesante disponer del espacio que nos proporciona Stack Overflow para promocionar proyectos de open source en los que estemos trabajando y así obtener más atención y, quién sabe, gente que se apunte a colaborar en ellos (así a bote pronto, se me ocurre traducir.win).

Hace un tiempo [ya tuvimos la oportunidad](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1185/83) pero no la aprovechamos. Creo que ahora sí podemos sacarle partido.

Answer (score 1):

Se podría promocionar mi emprendimiento de e-learning?

O eso sería pauta pagada? y de ser pagada , dónde puedo mirar las tarifas?

Comment: por lo que veo es de pago, ¿no? Se sale de lo que se permite en los avisos comunitarios. Para poner anuncios supongo que tienes que ir a https://stackoverflow.com/advertising

Comment: Bueno estuve mirando pero es prácticamente inalcanzable, precio de entrada 10.000 USD por mes , supongo que esta diseñado así para el mercado Norte americano. Esos Ads son para SO en ingles, que hay de SO en españól? Jamás he visto Ads :S

Comment: Ni idea. Lo suyo sería contactar con la empresa y pedir tarifas específicas para SOes