# Community Ads 2020

Tags: discusión, community-ads, anuncios-de-comunidad

Muchas gracias a [@Pikoh](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15301/pikoh) por la traducción.

---

¡Es hora de probar algo nuevo! Por favor, dad la bienvenida a una nueva iniciativa de [Publicidad basada en el Voto Libre para Proyectos de Código Abierto](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/) para Stack Overflow en Español! Cread un anuncio gráfico para un proyecto de programación de código abierto y publicarlo como respuesta a esta pregunta (en el formato correcto), y alimentará anuncios remanentes en vivo en Stack Overflow en español.

### Requisitos del anuncio

[Basado en una discusión anterior](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4668/10) y la experiencia en StackOverflow en inglés decidimos empezar con los siguientes requisitos.

Debe ser un anuncio **solicitar la participación y contribución de programadores que escriban código fuente real**. No se trata de anuncios de productos en sí, sólo porque sean de código abierto. Es para encontrar programadores que ayuden a contribuir con código u otras cosas de programación (documentación, revisión de código, corrección de errores, etc.).

Para que funcione, las respuestas que publiques en esta pregunta **deben** ajustarse a las siguientes reglas.

### Plantilla de respuestas

```
[![Texto alternativo si no se muestra la imagen.][1]][2]

  [1]: http://image-url
  [2]: http://clickthrough-url
```

Por favor, no añadas nada más al cuerpo de la publicación. Si quieres añadir algún comentario, manténlo en los comentarios.

### Requisitos de la imagen

- La imagen que crees debe ser de 300 por 250 píxeles, o el doble si el DPI es alto.
- Debe ser alojada a través de nuestro cargador de imágenes estándar (imgur)
- Debe ser GIF o PNG
- No hay GIFs animados
- Límite absoluto del tamaño del archivo de **150 KB**
- Debe tener un borde de 1px si (parte de) el fondo es blanco, 2px si la imagen es de alto DPI.

  - El texto de los anuncios debe estar en español.

La salida, que en última instancia se servirá en una ranura de anuncios en Stack Overflow en español, puede ser vista previamente haciendo clic a través de esta URL:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/ossads/300x250

### Umbral de Puntuación

Hay un **mínimo umbral de puntuación** que una respuesta debe cumplir (actualmente 6) antes de que sea servida por ese URL y se muestre en Stack Overflow en español. Puedes ver todos los anuncios que actualmente alcanzan el umbral y cumplen con nuestros criterios en esta página:

https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/4713

Comment: Posible tradución disponible en [Anuncios de promoción de la comunidad - 2017](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1185/83)

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' si, es prácticamente similar. Aunque habría que adaptarlo dado que no es exacto

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' ¡Lo siento! He echado de menos que hayamos tenido esta iniciativa SOes antes.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky in other sites the answer draft default to the format ([see MetsSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394409/1983854) or [Meta Spanish.SE](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3311/1674) for example). Is it possible to have the same in here?

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' ¡Gracias por plantear el problema! ¡Lo olvidé por completo! les pedí a mis colegas que agregaran el marcador de posición.

Comment: The page https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/4713 shows in English. I have reported it in Meta https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348876/209901

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' ¡Gracias! =)

Comment: Nicolas: I have added some associations in questions (example: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/384337/83), could you run the script to create the associations? Sorry for pinging here, since I am not a mod anymore I cannot superping in chat

Comment: Hey @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar'! ¡Muchas gracias! He agregado las asociaciones [al servidor](http://es.rudevs.ru/setting-string/) y he hecho ping a mis colegas para actualizar la configuración del sitio en SOen. =)

Comment: Fantástico, muchas gracias Nicolas :)

Answer (score 3):

[image: Recompensas en SOes ahora mismo]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Ayúdanos a crear una alternativa justa a las analíticas web]

Comment: Qué bien que publiquéis aquí también!